# Selenium : isDisplayed returns

Tags: exception, selenium, click

I'm quite new to Selenium so that question may be silly, but i cannot resolve it...

I'm trying to make a click() with Selenium (in Java, with Eclipse and Firefox and Chrome drivers) on an element that is definitely displayed and visible on the screen, but that returns `false` when i apply the `isDisplayed()` method on it. So i get an exception telling me that the element must be visible in order to perform an action on it.

I checked all parents div (i'm not using any iframe in my page), and some of them returns `true` as other returns false. Here is a small example of code of what i try to do :

`<div id=1><div id=2><div id=3><div id=4><img that i want to click on with selenium\></div></div></div></div>`

I want to click on the img with selenium, but it sees it as not displayed.

- the img is marked as not displayed
- the div4 is marked as not displayed
- the div3 is marked as displayed by selenium
- the div2 is marked as not displayed
- the div1 is marked as displayed, as all parents div

But i definitely can see the image and others elements in the same div on my screen.

Any help on that point ?
Thanks !

EDIT : I use JS to modify these properties, particularly div 3, which is not displayed and marked as not displayed at loading, but then after e few action, it became (it is and is marked as) displayed.

Edit 2 : I found out that the styles of the two divs marked as not displayed by selenium have both the style `display:block;` (seen in the chrome dev tools). Any ideas ?

Edit3 : based on the link given in the comments, i add the computed style of the div  :

- div4 : it has non zero height and width, display is set on block. It even has a min width and min height.
- div3 : it has non zero height and width, display is also set on block
- div2 : it has a 0 height a non zero width and a display:block; so it might be the problem.
- div1 : it has a 0 height, a non sero width, no display parameters, and hidden overflow-x and y. Thought this one is marked as deisplayed by Selenium...

Any ideas ?

Comment: Show us the *actual* HTML, and try to reproduce this on a public facing site.

Comment: the problem is that tthe actual HTML is quite big... And as it is modified by the JS, it won't even have its "final form". I'm trying to reproduce on a public website, with a smaller html file.

Comment: I do not manage to reproduce the same effect with simple html file...
However i did find that the divs marked as not displayed bu Selenium have both the syle="display:block;" in their computed styles (under Chrome).
Any ideas ?

Comment: Visit the spec that Selenium is based on: http://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#determining-visibility, specifically about element visibility. Does the element meet all those criteria?

Comment: Thanks for this link !
Based on that, i add the computed styles of the divs marked as not  displayed by selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem with a simple trick : call the Js function that is supposed to be triggered by the click, using

```
JavascriptExecutor js; 
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
} else {
    throw new Exception("  Webdriver do not manage JS");
}
js.executeScript("function()");
```

Another solution that could be suitable is to use a Robot to use the mouse to click on this img, if you have its coordinates of course (or if you can compute it) :

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mouseMove(300, 300);
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

Though i did not find a solution to the displayed/not displayed problem.
Enjoy :)